# ConTeXt: How to increase line-spacing in title?

Tags: titles, context, line-spacing, context-mkiv, pandoc

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) generates ConTeXT document titles using [a standard simple scheme](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Document_Titles#In_ConTeXt:_A_simple_solution) that sets the title in `\tfd`. I already changed the default font and size of `\tfd`. However, when a title is so long that it occupies more than one line, standard line-spacing turns out to be inadequate.

In below example, the "p" of "space" and the "l" of "long" are almost touching. Compare this with the "p" and "l" of the normal text below.

**Question:** How do I obtain a larger line-spacing by only modifying the preamble (i.e. not changing anything between `\starttext` and `\stoptext`)?

```
\setuptolerance[horizontal, tolerant, stretch]

\usetypescript[pagella]
\setupbodyfont[pagella,12pt]
\setupbodyfontenvironment[12pt][
  d=30pt,% For title
  a=12pt% For author & date
  ]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]

\starttext
\startalignment[center]
  \blank[2*big]
    {\tfd The space between the lines of this long title is not enough!}
  \blank[3*medium]
    {\tfa The author}
  \blank[2*medium]
    {\tfa September 10, 2013}
  \blank[3*medium]
\stopalignment

Space,\crlf
please!
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Comment: Untested: Try `{\bfd\setupinterlinespace ... \endgraf}`, etc.

Comment: Also use a comma after `a=12pt` rather than a `%` (easier to add delete more options).

Comment: As far as I understand the OP does not want to modify the pandoc template, so the interline space setup has to be injected without altering the code. The following is a hack which works for the title, but might break in other places: `\let\oldTFD\tfd\def\tfd{\oldTFD\setupinterlinespace\groupedcommand{}{\par}}`

Comment: @Marco: In this case, I think that it is relatively easy to modify the pandoc template. In fact, pandoc should be setting something like `\setupvariables[metadata][title=...,author=...,date=...]` and leave the formatting to a setup command in the preamble. I might just send a pull request to pandoc-templates, and then the OP wont have to change the template :)

Comment: @Aditya Fixing the pandoc template would be the best option, indeed. If you decide to send a fix upstream consider fixing descriptions as well, the default rendering is unusable (typeset the pandoc manual, then you'll know what I mean).

Comment: @Marco Your command does a perfect job! It would have never occurred to me to add a `\groupedcommand{}{\par}` at the end. Without it, it would not work. If you make an answer out of it, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The fix

As Aditya already pointed out, this is a bug in the [pandoc ConTeXt
template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.context#L58-70)
and should be fixed upstream. For the mean time the best you can do
is to edit the template and change the title setup to:

```
[…]
\startalignment[center]
  \blank[2*big]
  {\tfd\setupinterlinespace $title$\par}
[…]
```

This custom template can then be used using the `--template` switch.

```
pandoc --to=context --template=mytemplate.context input.md
```

A better solution would be to store the document metadata once and
use ConTeXt macros. This would semantically be a better markup
conversion from Markdown to ConTeXt. Furthermore, it simplifies the
resulting code when the data is used, for example on the title page
and the PDF meta data in `\setupinteraction`.

If you neither want to create a custom template nor wait for an
upstream fix, here's an ugly hack:

```
\let\oldTFD\tfd
\def\tfd
  {\oldTFD\setupinterlinespace\groupedcommand{}{\par}}
```

This redefines the `\tfd` font switch to automatically adjust the
interline space and finish the paragraph (see
[`\groupedcommand`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/groupedcommand)).
However, this changes the behaviour of the low-level `\tfd` command
and thus might break something else.

#### Reason

The reason the interline space is wrong is because the font is switched using
a rather low-level font command which does not adjust the interline spacing.
Another reason is that the line is not a paragraph and the line spacing
adjustment operates on a paragraph. Compare:

```
\starttext
  foo\par {\tfd Bar}                          \par
  foo\par {\tfd Bar\par}                      \par
  foo\par {\tfd\setupinterlinespace Bar}      \par
  foo\par {\tfd\setupinterlinespace Bar\par}  \par %% correct spacing

  foo\par {\switchtobodyfont[24pt]Bar}        \par
  foo\par {\switchtobodyfont[24pt]Bar\par}    \par %% correct spacing
\stoptext
```

As you can see `\tfd` requires setting the [interline
space](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupinterlinespace) as
well as a `\par`. The higher level font switch command
[`\switchtobodyfont`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/switchtobodyfont)
takes care of the interline spacing. But both of them require a
`\par`.

[image: result]

Comment: @Aditya Now that I understand how `\setupinterlinespace` works, I fully agree with this being a bug in the Pandoc template. Aditya, it would be great if you could also foresee `[title]`,`[author]` and `[date]` "handles" in the Pandoc template pull request. This would make further manipulation of these objects a lot easier whilst leaving the remainder of the document untouched.